# Edit filtered listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Can anyone help me with a solution or a different method for this? I would like to edit the filtered listbox

I'm trying to get a listbox that is able to display my sheet1 and be able to filter all the blanks/not found in column A. I also want to be able to edit the listbox aswell

I would like my userform2 listbox to display the sheet1 information.
There will also be a checkbox which will filter the listbox to show “not found” or blank lines.
If i double click the selected item on the listbox i would like to edit the information

for userform2

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
TextBox1.Enabled = True
TextBox1.Value = ListBox2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim rCell As Range
With ListBox2
Set rCell = Range(.RowSource).Resize(1).Offset(.ListIndex)
rCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
OptimizedMode True
If userform2.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Worksheets("Table").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Not Found", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
userform2.ListBox2.RowSource = vbNullString
userform2.ListBox2.ColumnHeads = False
Dim rng As Range
 Dim Cel1 As Range
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheets("Table")
 With ws
 LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 With userform2.ListBox2
 .ColumnCount = 1
 For Each Cel1 In rng
 .AddItem CStr(Cel1.Value)
 .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cel1.Offset(0, 1).Value

 Next Cel1
 End With
 End With

End If
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then

With userform2.ListBox2
.RowSource = "Table!A2:A1048576"
End With
End If
OptimizedMode False
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you want to be able to edit the listbox?

Comment: selecting item on listbox and using textbox to edit it

Answer (score 0):

I've re-designed my code and I believe this will achieve what you are after.

> **NOTE:** This code uses all default object names. You will need to modify it to target the names for your workbook, sheet, useform, controls etc, if you wish to implement into your project.

### In designing this answer I used the following:

- A new blank `Workbook` with 1 new `Worksheet`
- A new `UserForm` *(captioned "ListBox Editor")* with 1 `ListBox` that has 2 columns *(`ColumnCount = 2`)* and 1 `CheckBox` *(captioned "Show Blanks")*.

The sample data I used was in `Range("A1:A10")` filling only odd numbers from row 1. This allows testing for including/excluding blank/empty rows. Screenshots of the `Worksheet` and `UserForm` below.

### Worksheet data:

[image: Cells A1 through A10 filled with incrementing odd numbers in odd numbered rows]

### UserForms both with and without blanks in the listbox:

[image: UserForm with populated listbox of the Worksheet screenshot data, Include Blanks checkbox is unchecked and 5 items are in the list]
[image: UserForm with populated listbox of the Worksheet screenshot data, Include Blanks checkbox is checked and 10 items are in the list (including blanks)]

### All code is written in the code behind module for the `UserForm`

Most can be written into any other module with calls made to the subs/functions from the `UserForm`/`ListBox` events if you'd prefer not to have the working code in the UserForm module.

### Code blocks with explanations below (full code block at the end for copy/paste):

```
Option Explicit
```

> [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) should be included at the top of each and every code module you use. It forces explicit declaration of all variables which helps significantly in avoiding typo's in your code etc.

```
Private Sub PopulateListBox(ByVal IncludeBlanks As Boolean)
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .Clear
        For Each TargetCell In TargetWorksheet.Range("A1:A10")
            If Not IncludeBlanks Then
                If Not TargetCell.Value = "" Then
                    .AddItem TargetCell.Value
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = TargetCell.Row
                End If
            ElseIf IncludeBlanks Then
                .AddItem TargetCell.Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = TargetCell.Row
            End If
        Next TargetCell
        .ColumnWidths = ";0"    'Hides listbox column that holds row number
    End With
End Sub
```

> `PopulateListBox` is a subroutine I wrote to handle population of the items in the `ListBox`. It first clears the list, allowing each population of the listbox to be 'refreshed' data. Then it iterates through each `TargetCell` of the defined `Range`. If `IncludeBlanks` is `True` it has no conditions to meet and adds each cell value into the list, if `IncludeBlanks` is `False` it will only add the cell value to the list if the value is not `""`.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        PopulateListBox False
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        PopulateListBox True
    End If
End Sub
```

> This `_Click` event simply updates the `ListBox` list based on if the `CheckBox` is checked or not. The `CheckBox` represents if you are including blanks/empty cells or not so it passes `True` or `False` respective to it's `Value`, to the `IncludeBlanks` [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#argument) in `PopulateListBox`.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim NewValue As Variant
    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    NewValue = InputBox("What is the new value to replace " & UserForm1.ListBox1 & "?")
    
    If Not StrPtr(NewValue) = 0 Then             'Check user did NOT click cancel or [X]
        With ListBox1
            If NewValue = "" Then NewValue = vbNullString
            TargetWorksheet.Cells(.List(.ListIndex, 1), 1).Value = NewValue
            .AddItem NewValue, .ListIndex
            .RemoveItem .ListIndex
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

> The `_DblClick` [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dblclick-event) triggers the code when a list item is double clicked. This code first opens an `InputBox` to allow the user to enter a new value for the selected listbox item. When the user clicks OK or hit's <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the new value is first written to the `Cell` that the original value came from, then the new value is added as a new list item and finally the previous value is removed. If the user clicks [X] or 'Cancel' the code does *nothing*.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    PopulateListBox False
End Sub
```

> Much the same as the `Checkbox_Change` code, this simply populates the `ListBox` when the `UserForm` is first initialized. It's written to exclude blanks, specified by `False` for the `IncludeBlanks` argument.

### Put it all together and you have:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        PopulateListBox False
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        PopulateListBox True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim NewValue As Variant
    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    NewValue = InputBox("What is the new value to replace " & UserForm1.ListBox1 & "?")
    
    If Not StrPtr(NewValue) = 0 Then             'Check user did NOT click cancel or [X]
        With ListBox1
            If NewValue = "" Then NewValue = vbNullString
            TargetWorksheet.Cells(.List(.ListIndex, 1), 1).Value = NewValue
            .AddItem NewValue, .ListIndex
            .RemoveItem .ListIndex
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    PopulateListBox False
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateListBox(ByVal IncludeBlanks As Boolean)
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .Clear
        For Each TargetCell In Range("A1:A10")
            If Not IncludeBlanks Then
                If Not TargetCell.Value = "" Then
                    .AddItem TargetCell.Value
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = TargetCell.Row
                End If
            ElseIf IncludeBlanks Then
                .AddItem TargetCell.Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = TargetCell.Row
            End If
        Next TargetCell
        .ColumnWidths = ";0"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: my current code current does show my listbox and does filter it properly.. its the editing part of the listbox I'm having issues with

Comment: sorry but this doesn't really work with what I currently have

Comment: @araau11 You will need to elaborate on your question then. Please edit your question to provide more scope.

Comment: Hi @araau11, I've completely re-written my answer to better address the key points in your question.